# Unable to Launch Android Emulator in Visual Studio despite Trying Various Solutions

Tags: android-emulator, maui

I'm encountering difficulties launching the Android emulator in Visual Studio. Despite extensively searching through resources like YouTube tutorials, Stack Overflow threads, and GitHub discussions, none of the solutions I've found have resolved the issue.

To provide a clearer understanding, I've attached some screen captures illustrating the problem. Could someone please assist me in diagnosing and resolving this issue? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Have any individuals experienced issues with .NET MAUI?

Comment: this is an Android emulator issue, it has nothing to do with MAUI or Visual Studio

Comment: After days of trying, I finally figured out the solution when I realized that I have Windows 10 Enterprise N LTSC, which means that the media-related functionality is missing. So, I installed the missing feature, and now everything is okay, and the Android emulator works fine.